# How do I create a custom python interpreter? i.e. with certain modules already included?

Tags: python

If you've used Ruby on Rails, I'm thinking of the feature where the user types

> 'rails console'

and instantly gets a Ruby console with rails and the current app already loaded.
I want to make something like this for a python program I'm working on, does anyone know how I would get to type say,

> 'python myPythonConsole.py'

and open up a regular python interpreter but with my program and all its dependencies loaded?

Comment: Apparently Django also has this feature in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you might want `python -i myPythonConsole.py`. It gives you a console when the script has *finished* so you have to run your application in a different thread.

To create a console in a script you would use the [code module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#interactive-console-objects).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) (if you are not you should, it is an awesome python shell with TAB completion and many shortcuts) it is possible to [set up profiles](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/stable/html/config/customization.html#ipython-profiles), which basically are named configurations.

Each configuration can import modules (and do other stuff) at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Django does this with its "shell" command:

```
./manage.py shell
```

will open a Python shell with your Django settings loaded so you can import your project code interactively.

Source: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/shell.py

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is to use the [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable.  See the tutorial section [The interactive startup file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#the-interactive-startup-file).

Do your custom imports in a file `interpreter.py`, and configure

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=/path/to/interpreter.py
```

Next time your start Python, the custom code will be executed before you're dropped in the REPL shell.

Here's my customization:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
pp = pprint
P = Path

version = ".".join(str(number) for number in sys.version_info[0:3])
print(f"\nCustomized Python interpreter v{version} running from {sys.prefix}")
```